# Filter() operator is not continuing to remove Object from DOM

Tags: angular, dom, filter

I have filtered my Tasks and at first time, when I'm using click event, it Changes DOM, but after that doesn't continue filtering remaining tasks. I want to remove each task step-by-step.

This is my Service.ts:

```
deleteTasks(task: Task):Observable<Task[]>{
    return of(TASKS.filter(t => t.name !== task.name));
}
```

And this is my method in Component.ts:

```
deleteTask(task : Task){
  this.taskService.deleteTasks(task)
    .subscribe(tasks => this.tasks = tasks);
}
```

Component.html:

```
<button class="btn btn-danger btn-sm" (click)="deleteTask(task)">x</button>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are not updating your TASKS array which means everytime you click delete, you start from a full(initial) list instead of an updated list. Try something like this.

```
deleteTasks(task: Task):Observable<Task[]>{
    TASKS = TASKS.filter(t => t.name !== task.name)
    return of(TASKS)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

When you use the `filter()` function, it doesn't alter your original array. So you are never actually saving your previous filters. To do this you need to set your `TASKS` variable to your filter

```
deleteTasks(task: Task):Observable<Task[]>{
    TASKS = TASKS.filter(t => t.name !== task.name);
    return of(TASKS);
}
```